# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar 12.0.1.2 error in pom.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------    ----------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.061 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-19T14:37:43-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but     there is no POM in this directory (/Users/myname). Please verify you     invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException

I saved my ojdbc7 at /Users/myname/Downloads/ojdbc(1)

And that is what I am entering for my path so I don’t’ know where do I need to store this ojdbc. I don’t have Oracle on my machine. 
I am just practicing. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Go to the location of your ojdbc driver and open the command line there. You need to execute the following command in this directory

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -
 Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This will add ojdbc driver to your local m2 repository.

Comment: I got the error usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/java
-bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/java: No such file or directory. Sorry i am very new to programming. Thanks

Comment: do you have maven installed and configured? You can try to execute this command `mvn -v` in your cmd. The result should be something like this:
`Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T19:29:23+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Comment: Thanks! I did run this command mvn -v and this is what i got this result Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /Users/mynamej/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Did you try executing the command from the answer? Just go to the location of your ojdbc6.jar open cmd and run it.

Comment: This is my problem Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar 12.0.1.2 error in pom.xml in eclipse and you have seen the command i ran and the result it  gave me. Can you please give me all the steps number wise so that i don't get this error. The path for my Ojdbc is as follows /Users/myname/Downloads/ojdbc(1)Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Download the ojdbc driver and place it on the local drive. Run the following command either from the command prompt or from eclipse.

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:/jar//ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

If still see BUILD FAILURE error, in eclipse just remove mvn from the command and run.